# unable to call AOP is advice

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Aop is unable to trigger when userData method is called.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/service/userDate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Response> UserApp(@RequestBody UserVO userVO) {
    Response res = new Response(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    try {
        logger.debug("UserController : </ UserApp> ");
        res = userService.userApp(userVO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception in approveUser" + e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new Response(ErocErrorConstants.ERROR_STRING, HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED.value()),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.gf.service

public class UserService {
    @Transactional
    public Response userData(User userData) {
    }
}
```

```java
@Aspect
public class EmailAopService {
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.gf.service.UserService.userData(..)) && args(userData))")
    private void selectAll() {}

    @Before("selectAll()")
    public void logBefore(User userData) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `userData` method? In the snippet above i see you are calling `userApp` .

Comment: It's mistaken userApp only calling

Comment: did you add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to your config? Also your `selectAll()` method should have `User` argument `selectAll(User userData)` am not sure if that is the issue here.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn wiki syntax here, I just reformattted your code and added syntax highlighting. Furthermore, please learn what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and edit your question to be one. Nobody can help you if you only show an incoherent set of snippets. Also, please edit your question rather than correcting bugs in your code snippets via comment only. Thank you.